# Restrict admin to search specific content types

Tags: 7, search

1.Using [search configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config) module I have restricted the user role to search particular content type, this worked for me. But when I tried to apply the same approach to administrator this did work. I have unchecked the `Admin bypass (primary user with id 1)` the option too.

Is there a way to restrict the admin too to search specific content ?

2.And my second issue is about pagination, using the same module pagination is successfully applied, but for admin it is default set to 10 items per page, can I alter this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so; you would have to either:

1. Create a new role and then limit search configuration for that node.
2. Use Views to simply create another page for administrators where they can search the title/body, limited to a certain type.
3. Install [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) which will then allow you to change the *default* administration pages, and limit the displayed content types if you want.
4. If you need more complex search, look into [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) with [Search API Database Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db). These modules integrate with Views and you will be able to cover more complex scenarios.

Solutions 2, 3 and 4 use Views, so you will be able to change the number of items displayed per page.

Hope this helps.